# Python3 Iterate trough a variable length XML file

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a quite nested XML file which I have to iterate trough to extract records. I already followed some examples to read XML and I was sure that the XML was fixed length, but after some extraction I discovered that it wasn't.
Here's my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('EcommProdotti.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print("Printing on file...")

with open("prodotti.txt", "w") as f:
for child in root:
    for element in child.iter('Products'):
        for sub_element in element.iter('Product'):
            length = len(sub_element) + 1    
            my_string = sub_element[1].text + " " + sub_element[2].text + " " + sub_element[9].text + "\n"
            f.write(my_string)
```

As you can see, my records are in the sub_element node, and this may be variable, as per the following XML File example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- File in formato Easyfatt-XML creato con Danea Easyfatt - www.danea.it/software/easyfatt -->
<!-- Per importare o creare un file in formato Easyfatt-Xml, consultare la documentazione tecnica: www.danea.it/software/easyfatt/xml -->
<EasyfattProducts AppVersion="2" Creator="Danea Easyfatt Enterprise One  2019.45d" CreatorUrl="http://www.danea.it/software/easyfatt" Mode="full" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://www.danea.it/public/prodotti.xsd">
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <InternalID>35</InternalID>
      <Code>00035</Code>
      <Description>12 PEZZI ROTOLO SACCHETTO IGIENICO PER CANI</Description>
      <DescriptionHtml></DescriptionHtml>
      <Category>ACCESSORI PER ANIMALI</Category>
      <Subcategory>PRODOTTI IGIENE E PULIZIA</Subcategory>
      <Vat Perc="22" Class="Imponibile" Description="Imponibile 22%">22</Vat>
      <Um>PZ</Um>
      <NetPrice1>2.46</NetPrice1>
      <GrossPrice1>3</GrossPrice1>
      <Barcode>8805786177364</Barcode>
      <SupplierCode>0004</SupplierCode>
      <SupplierName>LED STORM SRLS</SupplierName>
      <SupplierNetPrice>1.898</SupplierNetPrice>
      <SupplierGrossPrice>2.3156</SupplierGrossPrice>
      <SizeUm>cm</SizeUm>
      <WeightUm>kg</WeightUm>
      <GrossWeight>0.2</GrossWeight>
      <ManageWarehouse>true</ManageWarehouse>
      <OrderWaitDays>10</OrderWaitDays>
      <AvailableQty>6</AvailableQty>
      <Notes></Notes>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <InternalID>1155</InternalID>
      <Code>01144</Code>
      <Description>ADVANCE CANE ATOPIC MEDIUM/MAXI 3 KG</Description>
      <DescriptionHtml></DescriptionHtml>
      <Category>ALIMENTI PER ANIMALI</Category>
      <Subcategory>ALIMENTI CURATIVI (DIETETICI)</Subcategory>
      <Vat Perc="22" Class="Imponibile" Description="Imponibile 22%">22</Vat>
      <Um>PZ</Um>
      <NetPrice1>20.48</NetPrice1>
      <GrossPrice1>24.99</GrossPrice1>
      <Barcode>8410650170695</Barcode>
      <ProducerName>Affinity</ProducerName>
      <SupplierCode>0033</SupplierCode>
      <SupplierName>LOCONTE VITO &amp; C. S.A.S.</SupplierName>
      <SupplierProductCode>ADV924483</SupplierProductCode>
      <SupplierNetPrice>13.0438</SupplierNetPrice>
      <SupplierGrossPrice>15.9134</SupplierGrossPrice>
      <SizeUm>cm</SizeUm>
      <WeightUm>kg</WeightUm>
      <GrossWeight>3</GrossWeight>
      <ManageWarehouse>true</ManageWarehouse>
      <AvailableQty>8</AvailableQty>
      <Notes></Notes>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <InternalID>203</InternalID>
      <Code>00198</Code>
      <Description>ADVANTIX CANE FINO A 4 KG</Description>
      <DescriptionHtml></DescriptionHtml>
      <Category>ACCESSORI PER ANIMALI</Category>
      <Subcategory>ANTIPARASSITARI</Subcategory>
      <Vat Perc="10" Class="Imponibile" Description="Imponibile 10%">10</Vat>
      <Um>PZ</Um>
      <NetPrice1>19.82</NetPrice1>
      <GrossPrice1>21.8</GrossPrice1>
      <Barcode>4007221009597</Barcode>
      <ProducerName>Bayer</ProducerName>
      <SupplierCode>0033</SupplierCode>
      <SupplierName>LOCONTE VITO &amp; C. S.A.S.</SupplierName>
      <SupplierProductCode>BYR03382048</SupplierProductCode>
      <SupplierNetPrice>16.25</SupplierNetPrice>
      <SupplierGrossPrice>17.875</SupplierGrossPrice>
      <SizeUm>cm</SizeUm>
      <WeightUm>kg</WeightUm>
      <GrossWeight>0.04</GrossWeight>
      <ManageWarehouse>true</ManageWarehouse>
      <OrderWaitDays>10</OrderWaitDays>
      <AvailableQty>10</AvailableQty>
      <Notes></Notes>
      <ExtraBarcodes>
        <Barcode>103629046</Barcode>
        <Barcode>4007221046424</Barcode>
      </ExtraBarcodes>
    </Product>
</EasyfattProducts>
```

So, how do I iterate trough this file? Thanks in advance for your time and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XPath](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) query to avoid the direct item indexing:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('EcommProdotti.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for product in root.findall(".//Products/Product"):
    for field in ['Code', 'Description', 'GrossPrice1','SupplierProductCode']:
        value = product.find(field)
        if  value != None:
            print (value.text, end=' ')
        else:
            print ('Not defined', end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: It's okay with that, but doesn't seem to help with fields which are not always present (for example <SupplierProductCode> which seems to be present only in some records

Comment: I updated this example to show how to process absent fields.